# Remove all string before last underscore

Tags: php, preg-replace

i try to get the last name after the **underscore** dash

```
$x = "John_Chio_Guy";
```

output should be : `Guy`

and this is my current code :

```
$x = "John_Chio_Guy";
$x = preg_replace("/^[^_]*_\s*/", "", $x);
echo $x;
//output : Chio_Guy
```

Comment: Those are not dashes.

Comment: Why regex? How about `explode`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strrpos` and `substr`:

```
$x = "John_Chio_Guy";

$pos = strrpos($x, "_");

echo substr($x,$pos+1);
```

Result : Guy

Comment: This breaks if the name doesn't actually contain a `_`; `strrpos` will return false, which will convert to 0 for the add, so you get everything from position 1 on -- that is, you lose the first letter.  Whether that's an issue worth caring about, depends on whether the data will *always* contain a `_`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use explode function this is too simple

```
<?php

$x = "John_Chio_Guy";

//explode the string
$explode = explode('_', $x);

//get the end value
echo end($explode);

?>
```